# Chrome Timeline does not show all calls on a flame chart

Tags: google-chrome, timeline, flamegraph

While using Google Chrome Timeline feature I have noticed a strange thing. On my PC in a workplace flame chart is very flat, showing only 1-2 function calls deep. My first thought was: "Well, that is the way this thing works". But when I opened the same webapp from home and a flame chart was much taller, showing all function calls.

Both browsers are in the same version (51.0.2704.84 m - latest at the moment). All settings in DevTools are same.

Flame chart from computer at work:
[image: PC]

Flame chart from computer at home:
[image: Laptop]

My question is simple: why computer at work does not show full call graph and how can I fix this?

Comment: Hi, did you ever fix this problem? Im having a similar one

Answer (score 0):

Is everything checked under the Event Log tab (below)? I see that painting and rendering events are not visible in your bottom screenshot.

Comment: Yes. In both cases everything is checked.

Comment: I can't for the life of me find a way to make Chrome not show all JS events, and there doesn't seem to be a reason for making it do so either - so it's not a feature. Are both profiles supposed to show the exact same processing? In other words, are the applications and the executed steps 100% identical? I have to ask because your home PC profile shows more CPU activity, and I see that the application is running on localhost on both PCs.

Comment: Code is 100% identical: exactly the same commit, exactly the same data. What I have noticed is home PC stops on async callbacks: it shows function that have callback registration (ex. function that invokes setTimeout), but does not show callback handler itself.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug on your work computer. It shows no JS frames at all. If it's still reproducible please file it at https://crbug.com

I assume you were recording with JS Profile checkbox marked.